# Neo4j/Cypher attempting to UNWIND a list of user ids, create one Notification and relationship to all users that were matched

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-apoc

I have this cypher query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (allMentionedUsers:User)
WHERE allMentionedUsers.id in $mentions
UNWIND allMentionedUsers as mentionedUser
CREATE (n:Notification {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(),
    notificationType: 'MENTION',
    notifierName: u.username,
    body: 'mentioned you',
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime()
})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(n)-[:NOTIFIES]->(mentionedUser)
```

that checks the variable `$mentions` (list of string ids) for possible User matches and then UNWINDs all matched users to create a Notification and subsequent relationships. `p` is another parent node and not too important for this question. `u` is also not important here and working as expected.

Essentially I want there to be one Notification with a `NOTIFIES` relationship to one or more User nodes.

Currently the above statement creates a separate Notification per user. Anyone see how I can modify it to create one single Notification node that has as many `NOTIFIES` relationships to users that were matched?

It is creating multiple Notification nodes because the create is inside the UNWIND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UNWIND isn't actually doing anything, it's a no-op here. UNWIND works on lists, but `allMentionedUsers` isn't a list (and it would be a good idea to use singular instead of plural for the variable name.

You could MERGE the notification first, and only afterwards create the rest of the pattern.

```
...
MERGE (n:Notification {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(),
    notificationType: 'MENTION',
    notifierName: u.username,
    body: 'mentioned you',
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime()
})
WITH u, p, n
OPTIONAL MATCH (mentionedUser:User)
WHERE mentionedUser.id in $mentions
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(n)
MERGE (n)-[:NOTIFIES]->(mentionedUser)
```

Or you could collect the users into a list and do the same, which may work a bit better since the MERGE operation would happen once instead of for each row:

```
...
OPTIONAL MATCH (mentionedUser:User)
WHERE mentionedUser.id in $mentions
WITH u, p, collect(mentionedUser) as allMentionedUsers
MERGE (n:Notification {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(),
    notificationType: 'MENTION',
    notifierName: u.username,
    body: 'mentioned you',
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime()
})
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(n)
FOREACH (mentionedUser IN allMentionedUsers | 
  MERGE (n)-[:NOTIFIES]->(mentionedUser) )
```

I'm using a FOREACH to process the notification per mentioned user, as it will keep the cardinality down, which is important if you don't have any other operations to perform per mentioned user.

One final alternative is to keep allMentionedUsers in a list from start to end, but this requires using a list comprehension and pattern comprehension, as well as using a weird alternate pattern syntax to capture the pattern of a single node in a multi-part pattern (since Cypher doesn't seem to consider single-nodes as valid patterns for a pattern comprehension).

```
...
WITH u, p, [id in $mentions | [(user:User {id:id})-[*0]-() | user][0]] as allMentionedUsers
MERGE (n:Notification {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(),
    notificationType: 'MENTION',
    notifierName: u.username,
    body: 'mentioned you',
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime()
})
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(n)
FOREACH (mentionedUser IN allMentionedUsers | 
  MERGE (n)-[:NOTIFIES]->(mentionedUser) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Merge function instead of Create.  Merge will not create a duplicate because if it sees the same node/relationships exists, then it will skip it and not create another one. It is like a MATCH then CREATE if not found.  Meanwhile, CREATE will not check if the same node/relationshps exists or not.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (allMentionedUsers:User)
WHERE allMentionedUsers.id in $mentions
UNWIND allMentionedUsers as mentionedUser
MERGE (p)-[:HAS_NOTIFICATION]->(n:Notification {
    id: apoc.create.uuid(),
    notificationType: 'MENTION',
    notifierName: u.username,
    body: 'mentioned you',
    createdAt: datetime(),
    updatedAt: datetime()
})-[:NOTIFIES]->(mentionedUser)
```

Comment: I had tried that, but it is still creating multiple Notification nodes.